# AJAX/PHP Issues

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm updating a messaging system on my website, and I can't figure out why the following chunk of code isn't working At All:

```
function sendReply(id,from,to)
{
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML;
    var body = document.getElementById("body").innerHTML;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (id.length==0) {
        document.getElementById("userMessagingBackground").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sendOutReply.php?from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("userMessagingBackground").style.display = "none";
}
```

So...Uh...Is there anything wrong with this?  If not...Here's the PHP part:

```
<?php
    $to = $_GET['to'];
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(Database Connection Stuff);
    $username = $_GET['user'];
    if (!empty($_GET['body'])) {
        $sub = $_GET['subject'];
        $body = "Sent by $username:\n---\n" 
            . $_GET['body'] . "\n\n------------------------\n\n"
            . $receivedMsg;
        $STM = "INSERT INTO messagingTable 
            (new, sender, receiver, subject, message, sentDate) 
            VALUES ('1', '$username', '$to', 'RE: $subject', '$body', NOW())";
        $sendMessage = mysqli_query($dbc, $STM);

        $findReceiver = "SELECT * FROM usersTable WHERE username = '$to'";
        $getTo = mysqli_query($dbc,$findReceiver);
        $toRow = mysqli_fetch_array($getTo);

        if ($toRow['emailOnPm'] == 1) {
            mail($toRow['email'],$sub,$body, "From: AllThemGames.com");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what are you seeing?

Comment: What are you doing in the callback?

Comment: Also what version of PHP are you using on your site?

Comment: @John: Nothing at all is happening.

Comment: @tafoo: I'm sending a message to my database...

Comment: What happens when you debug trace? Where does it seem to go wrong?

Comment: What's the 'id' parameter for? You only check it's length, but don't use it anywhere else. If `id.length==0`, then nothing will happen...

Comment: The 'id' parameter is to check if it is a hacker trying to glitch the system or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax call function is missing a callback function. For example:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4)
        //Do you call back
)
```

Comment: You don't NEED a callback, but it will definitely help you assess if there is an error in your javascript or if there's an error in your php script.  I would add one and (using firebug) set a breakpoint at the callback and check the values of the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Solely a suggestion from personal preference. Rather than set a break point I'd recommend injecting console.log() statements into your code to track its progress.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
mlhttp.send();
```

Should have

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

I am not sure that this is the complete answer, but worth a shot...

Comment: Turns out the 'x' just got deleted as I added it as a code block.  It was actually just fine when it came to that, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see with Firebug if you do send a request?

If it does correctly, the problem is on the PHP side :).

Besides, you may be able to see a 500 error returned. If that is the case, check your server's error logs.

Next, we need to see **what** is not working.

Is that the MySQL requests? Is that the mail function? Use some `echo` statements to find out more about what is wrong and right.

By the way, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Read [here](http://www.learnphponline.com/security/sql-injection-prevention-mysql-php) or [here](http://ezinearticles.com/?SQL-Injection-Protection-in-PHP-With-PDO&id=1815110) to find out how to protect yourself from them (if you want to dive into PDO, [here is a link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) that will help you get started).

Also, seriously, [read this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/). Basically, you should learn how to debug to find out where the errors are. This will help you to find out how stupid you can be (no offense, everyone can be ;)), and will also get us to help you better.

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)